# IBM Bluemix student accounts

Tags: ibm-cloud

In IBM Bluemix, can you create anonymous student accounts such as Student-1, Student-2, etc. ? I do not want to share student names.

Answer (score 2):

you can't. each student has to register his/her own trial account. After that, you can add them to your bluemix organization/space